# How to rename a certain prefix in multiple files?

Tags: command-line, files, batch-rename

I have a folder that contains over 500+ files with a certain prefix. Those files are spread in multiple folders in one directory. My objective is to re-name that prefix in those multiple files.

**Sample File Names and Paths:**

- MyFiles/my-**old**-FileOfAlice.txt
- MyFiles/Folder 1/my-**old**-FileOfTom.odt
- MyFiles/Folder 2/my-**old**-FileOfJane.doc

**The Objective Is To Rename Them To:**

- MyFiles/my-**new**-FileOfAlice.txt
- MyFiles/Folder 1/my-**new**-FileOfTom.odt
- MyFiles/Folder 2/my-**new**-FileOfJane.doc

**Notes:**

- The files do not have the same extension.
- The files are spread in multiple folders under the same directory. I am using Kubuntu 16.10. Any Ubuntu oriented answer will be accepted and appreciated.

**Any command line, program, guide, tutorial, or link would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I assume you want to replace **old**, but how is it embedded, any specific characters like `-`, or other markers? An example? You wouldn't want to define the replacement too broad.

Comment: @JacobVlijm : Yes, there is the dash character " - " before and after the prefix that I want to replace. Exactly in the same order and format shown in the example above. That is: "word-WordToReplace-word.Extention". Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
find -name "*-old-*" -exec rename 's/-old-/-new-/' {} \;
```

This searches for files containing `-old-` recursively beginning in your current directory and renames them by replacing the `-old-` with `-new-`.

Note: replacing `old` may be enough, but I included the `-` in case, there is a second `old` in the name (like my-**old**-F**old**ers.doc).